# Edge extension failed the package compliance test on submission

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I recently submitted my edge extension to microsoft store to get reviewed. But it failed the package compliance test. I am not sure how to proceed now. I went through my manifest json for invalid entries and there were none. I have pasted my manifest file details and below is the error report.

[image]

> The JSON schema validation test detected the following errors:
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XComment' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'. at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.BrowserExtensionApp.JsonManifestValidation.GetAppxExtensions(String appxManifestPath) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.BrowserExtensionApp.JsonManifestValidation.Test(BrowserExtensionApp browserExtensionApp) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "AB C",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author" : "AB C",
    "description": "Edge extension",
    "homepage_url" : "https://AB.C.com/online/main",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19" : "images/PNG/ABC-19-disable.png",
            "20" : "images/PNG/ABC-20-disable.png",
            "25" : "images/PNG/ABC-25-disable.png",
            "30" : "images/PNG/ABC-30-disable.png",
            "35" : "images/PNG/ABC-35-disable.png",
            "38" : "images/PNG/ABC-38-disable.png",
            "40" : "images/PNG/ABC-40-disable.png"
        },
        "default_title": "AB C",
        "default_popup" : "html/ABCPopup.html"
    },
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "edge": {
            "browser_action_next_to_addressbar": true
        }
    },
    "minimum_edge_version" : "42.17134.1.0",
    "background": {
        "persistent" : true,
        "page": "html/background.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["js/ABCUtil.min.js", "js/ABCCS.min.js","js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "cookies",
        "idle",
        "privacy",
        "notifications",
        "https://AB.C.com/",
        "https://AB.C.eu/",
        "https://AB.C.com.cn/",
        "https://AB.C.in/",
        "contextMenus",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "clipboardRead",
        "unlimitedStorage"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com/css https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/ ; font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/css https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/ ; default-src 'self';script-src 'self'; frame-src 'self';img-src 'self' data: blob:;connect-src https://AB.C.com https://AB.C.eu https://AB.C.in https://AB.C.com.cn",
    "icons": {
        "16" : "images/PNG/ABC-32.png",
        "48": "images/PNG/ABC-48.png",
        "128": "images/PNG/ABC-128.png"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "/html/ABCSSFrame.html",
        "/html/ABCUSFrame.html",
        "/html/ABCMSFrame.html",
        "/html/ABCResetProgress.html",
        "/html/ABCGetPP.html",
        "/html/ABCInsecureFrame.html",
        "/images/secret11x11.svg",
        "/images/loading.gif",
        "/images/tpband-close.png",
        "/images/clearicon.png"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any code, functions, methods, images, logos which are already used by any other extension or which are not allowed to used in an extension or due to any other reason MS Store can give you these kind of errors.

To get more information about Microsoft store policies, You can refer link below.

[Microsoft Store Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/windows/agreements/store-policies)

You can first try to use Windows App Certification Kit.

To improve the chances of your extension getting published to the Microsoft Store, you'll need to install and run the Windows App Certification Kit. This runs a series of tests on your extension package to ensure that it's ready for the Microsoft Store.

Reference:

[Running the Windows App Certification Kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/running-the-windows-app-certification-kit)

Comment: I did try testing it in Windows App Ceritification Kit, it returned the same error result shown in the above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a comment in my AppxManifest.xml, microsoft does not allow comments in xml files for some reason. I removed the comment to fix this.